# Is any mirror of archive.raspberrypi.org available?

Tags: apt, pi-gen

*Notice: it's not about mirrors of `archive.raspbian.org` but `archive.raspberrypi.org`. Earlier one has so many mirrors all over the world.*

### Background

I'm building a customized Raspbian image with [RPi-Distro/pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen) and every time I build the image it fetches fundamental packages from `archive.raspberrypi.org` like `raspberrypi-kernel`.

The bandwidth of `archive.raspberrypi.org` is super narrow and takes so long time to download such kernels and other stuff. It's not convenient especially when I experiment with it and doing try-and-errors.

### About making my own mirrors

It's better to have publicly available mirrors instead of making a private mirror of `archive.raspberrypi.org` while it's a clever choice.

Comment: *"It's better to have publicly available mirrors..."* -> Pretty sure you could just download the whole shebang, attach a webserver, and it use it locally.  No bandwidth issues there and much simpler.

Comment: Yes, yes I know that. Needless to say, "download the whole shebang" from a repository consumes a big amount of storage. It's the last resort. Furthermore, I'm sure you ever used some APT mirrors and was happy with it. Having multiple mirrors is a big benefit for people in terms of availability and bandwidth.

Comment: Now I'm thinking of writing thin and simple transparent proxy to reduce the pain without downloading/mirroring a whole repository. I'll post here when existing solution is found or I write some codes.

Comment: Why don't you use a couple HTTP proxies as mirrors?

Comment: @user96931 That's a handy choice and will solve this problem personally and temporarily. I really wonder if there are any public mirrors, and why they don't exist for now.

Comment: Here's my answer: https://github.com/puhitaku/empera . It perfectly works with RPi-Disto/pi-gen while there's no test code yet (improvement is planned). If you want a well-known and stable solution, use Squid or something. And pray for a public mirror to come.

Answer (score 1):

Upon a Google search, I have found two mirrors available both at [rpi.rutgers.edu](http://rpi.rutgers.edu/archive.raspberrypi.org/) and [mirrors.ustc.edu.cn](https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/archive.raspberrypi.org/). I have not tested the bandwidth or integrity of either of these sites, but since they are .edu I believe they should be credible. I wasn't able to find any more than these two, but they may exist. Alternatively, if you would like to host your own copy of archive.raspberrypi.org, I have found a [helpful script on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/pierew/6d1611b7b5f5e829094c356dfbbb4fd3) to do just that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this half-year-old question. Temporarily I'm a bit away from RPi development so I'd accept it later.